# How to trigger on alt without triggering on alt+shift and alt+ctrl

Tags: autohotkey

In ahk2

```
LAlt & l::
```

triggers on lalt+l, lalt+shift+l and lalt+ctrl+shift+l.
I want it to trigger on lalt+l only. In other words I want it to NOT trigger on lalt+shift+l and lalt+ctrl+shift+l.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says:

> Note: For **combinations with standard modifier keys**, it is usually
> better to **use the standard syntax**. For example, use **<+s::** rather than
> LShift & s::.

In this case try

```
; LAlt + l
<!l::
```

**<!** is the symbol for the left Alt key.

See [Hotkey Modifier Symbols](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)